# Странное поведение метода split

Tags: java

Я пытаюсь разбить строчку на массив подстрок - нашел метод split. Но чему бы не была равна строка изначально, всегда возвращается пустой массив.

Код:

```
String testSplit = "blog.hashcode.ru"; 
String[] result = testSplit.split("."); 
// по идее размер массива должен быть равен трём
System.out.println(result.length());
```

Результат:

```
0
```

Comment: а так все работает:

      final String [] result = testSplit.split ( "\\." );

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это потому, что split работает с regexp

```
"blog.hashcode.ru".split(Pattern.quote("."))
```

Answer (score 5):

Точка является зарезервированным символом регулярных выражений. Поэтому правильно будет сделать одно из двух:

- экранировать точку (вместо `"."` написать `"\\."`);
- последовать совету @cy6erGn0m .