# почему split определяет точку как пробел?

Tags: java, split

Необходимо разделить числа пробелом чтобы потом определить какой тип числа вводится и какая операция(+ - * /).

Но почему-то split точку не так считает....Как поправить?
И как определить **str.charAt(i)==какой тип?**

```
   str="3.5 + 2";
   str.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки в Яве являются неизменяемыми объектами.
если ты думаешь что `str.split(" ");` поделило строку то нет, я тебя огорчу.

`String[] result=str.split(...);` вот как надо. Нужно обращаться к элементу массива. И вообще, это дубликат. вот [вот тебе сюда за подробностями.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2841/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-split) учись пользоваться поиском до задания вопроса

Comment: String tmp[];             
       tmp=str.split("\\u0020");
       for(int i =0; i < tmp.length ; i++)
        System.out.println("TMP= "+tmp[i]);

Comment: вообщем спасибо разобрался в тот же момент как вы написали

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста...  float peremf;    if (tmp[i].indexOf(".")==1) {
           peremf=tmp[i];
       }              Как взять значение в строке и присвоить переменной с точкой??? @argamidon

Answer (score 2):

Я конечно я Java не шарю и не программировал не разу. Но по-моему у вас ошибочное обращение к массиву.
Вы "str" разбиваете командой split на массив, указывая разделитель символ пробела.
Split возвращает массив, а вы обращаетесь не к элементу массива, а к символу.
Что если сделать обращение:

```
System.out.println(str(i))
```

Comment: НО как же тогда обратиться к разделенной части?...